# Validacion para no ingresar datos repetidos a base de datos fallida

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin, backend

Estoy haciendo un carrito de compras para mi Ecommerce, mi problema es que si la persona le da comprar al producto este se va al carrito de compras, que en la base de datos seria la tabla pedido y alli se guarda el registro. Lo que pasa es que si le doy 100 veces en comprar al mismo producto, se guardara 100 veces ese producto en la base de datos y no quiero que pase esto, por lo tanto puse una validacion, lo que hace es mirar los registros en la base de datos y si alguno de los codproductos que estan en la base de datos es igual al codproducto que le estoy pasando cuando le doy click en añadir al carro de compras, no me lo deje ingresar y dice que el producto ya fue agregado.
Antes de agregar esa validación me funcionaba perfecto, pero cuando la agregue no me funciona y no veo los errores.

ESTE ES EL CODIGO DE validar_inicio_compra.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $response=new stdClass();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['codusu'])) {
        $response->state=false;
        $response->detail="No esta logeado";
        $response->open_login=true;
    }else{
        include_once('../_conexion.php');
        $codusu=$_SESSION['codusu'];
        $codpro=$_POST['codpro'];
        $cantpro=$_POST['cantprod'];
        
        $datos_consulta=[];
        $i=0;
        $sql="select * from pedido where estado=1";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $obj=new stdClass();
            $obj->codproduct=$row['codpro'];
            $datos_consulta[$i]=$obj;
            if(!($codpro==$datos[i].codproduct)){
                $sql="INSERT INTO pedido
                (codusu,codpro,fecped,estado,dirusuped,telusuped,cantpro)
                VALUES
                ($codusu,$codpro,now(),1,'','',$cantpro)";
                $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                if ($result) {
                    $response->state=true;
                    $response->detail="Producto agregado";
                    //header('Location: ../');
                }   
                    }
                    elseif($codpro==$datos[i].codproduct){
                    $response->state=false;
                    $response->detail="El producto ya fue agregado. Intente con otro producto.";
                    }
                $i++;
                
            }
            $response->datos=$datos_consulta;
            mysqli_close($con);

            }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
```

ESTE EL DE Producto.php por si lo necesitan

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include 'head.php';?>
<body>
<?php include 'nav.php';?>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="content-page">
            <section>
                <div class="part1">
                    <img id="idimg" src="assets/products/crepe.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="part2">
                    <h2 id="idtitle">NOMBRE PRINCIPAL</h2>
                    <h1 id="idprice">S/. 35.<span>99</span></h1>
                    <h3 id="iddescription">Descripcion del producto</h3>
                    <br><br>
                    <div id="quantity-prod" class="quantiproduc">
                            <h2>Cantidad de producto</h2>
                            <input type="number" name="quantity-input" id="quantity-input" value="1" min="1" max="100" step="1 ">
                    </div>
                    <button onclick="iniciar_compra()">Comprar</button>
                </div>
                
                
            </section>
            <div class="title-section">Productos destacados</div>
            <div class="products-list" id="space-list">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var p='<?php echo $_GET["p"]; ?>';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'servicios/producto/get_all_products.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{},
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    let html='';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.datos.length; i++) {
                        if (data.datos[i].codpro==p) {
                            document.getElementById("idimg").src="assets/products/"+data.datos[i].rutimapro;
                            document.getElementById("idtitle").innerHTML=data.datos[i].nompro;
                            document.getElementById("idprice").innerHTML=formato_precio(data.datos[i].prepro);
                            document.getElementById("iddescription").innerHTML=data.datos[i].despro;
                        }
                        if(!(data.datos[i].codpro==p)){
                        html+=
                        '<div class="product-box">'+
                            '<a href="producto.php?p='+data.datos[i].codpro+'">'+
                                '<div class="product">'+
                                    '<img src="assets/products/'+data.datos[i].rutimapro+'">'+
                                    '<div class="detail-title">'+data.datos[i].nompro+'</div>'+
                                    '<div class="detail-description">'+data.datos[i].despro+'</div>'+
                                    '<div class="detail-price">'+formato_precio(data.datos[i].prepro)+'</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</a>'+
                        '</div>';
                        }
                    }
                
                    document.getElementById("space-list").innerHTML=html;
                },
                error:function(err){
                    console.error(err);
                }
            });
        });
        function formato_precio(valor){
            //10.99
            let svalor=valor.toString();
            let array=svalor.split(".");
            return "S/. "+array[0]+".<span>"+array[1]+"</span>";
        }
        function iniciar_compra(){
            
            
            $.ajax({
                url:'servicios/compra/validar_inicio_compra.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{
                    codpro:p,
                    cantprod:document.getElementById("quantity-input").value
                    
                    
                },
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.state) {
                        alert(data.detail);
                    }else{
                        alert(data.detail);
                        if (data.open_login) {
                            open_login();
                        }
                    }
                },
                error:function(err){
                    console.error(err);
                }
            });
        }
        function open_login(){
            window.location.href="login.php";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Esto es como esta conformado la tabla pedido
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que la base de datos no esta normalizada, pero lo hice asi para no demorarme tanto, despúes cuando solucione este error la normalizo y la adapto de una mejor manera.

Comment: Buenas, podrias solucionarlo a nivel db, agregando un indice "unique" en la tabla, de esa forma el motor va a generar un error, y vas a poder capturar el error para comunicar al usuario. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/

Comment: Obvio tambien lo podes prevenir desde una capa superior, osea desde php, pero a mi criterio seria "sobreingenieria"

Comment: @Karlkno Muy buena solucion, no se me habia ocurrido. Como capturo ya el error, porque me esta saltando una ventana emergente que dice undefined, nose porque no me esta cogiendo la que dice "No se pudo agregar producto. Intente más tarde"

Comment: Tecnicamente seria asi: Con php, al hacer el "insert in to...", de un producto que ya esta en la tabla (segun el indice unico que creaste), esa query va a fallar, vos deberias capturar el codigo de error de dicha falla, y si es "1062" (Duplicate entry) . Envias al front un aviso de dicha falla.

Comment: Ahora pregunto, que te responde el server cuando haces la peticion?. No lo que  la ventana emergente dice.

Comment: Aparte de lo que te ha dicho muy acertadamente @Karlkno, la lógica de tu programa está mal planteada. Si hablamos de un carrito, lo propio sería permitir agregar cantidades a un determinado producto, por tanto es posible que te haga falta una nueva tabla donde expreses las compras, usando en esa tabla el ID del producto y teniendo una columna para la cantidad de productos.

Comment: @Karlkno Me tira de error en consola lo siguiente: ´<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'codprod_repetido' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce\servicios\compra\validar_inicio_compra.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce\servicios\compra\validar_inicio_compra.php(17): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO ped...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce\servicios\compra\validar_inicio_compra.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />´

Comment: Se que la linea que me da error es $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql), se supone que como no se cumple este if if ($result) {
  $response->state=true;
  $response->detail="Producto agregado";
  }                                                                                                                  deberia pasar al else que es else{
  $response->state=false;
  $response->detail="No se pudo agregar producto. Intente más tarde";
 }

Comment: Pero la ejecucion del programa se queda es en el  $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) cuando da el error y no se mete al else para que en la alerta me diga "No se pudo agregar producto. Intente más tarde"

Comment: Estoy pensando que con trycatch se puede solucionar, pero no se como hacer que el $response->detail="No se pudo agregar producto. Intente más tarde"; se pase de forma correcta por ajax a la clase producto.php y en la alerta que me emerge por ya estar el producto en el carrito me diga ese detail que le estoy pasando desde validar_inicio_compra.php

Comment: Se me complica un poco analizar tu codigo, mas que nada por que las funciones nativas de php "mysqli_..." no se usan hace años. Pero seria algo asi:                                                         try {
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
    if ($query === FALSE) {
        throw new Exception($this->mysqli->error);
    }
    // aca podes procesar los resultados ok
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if($e->getCode()==1062){
        $response->detail = "El producto ya fue agregado. Intente con otro producto." . $e->getCode();
    }else{
        //aca el error es otro.
    }
}